# Shapely affine transformations with bounds of GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas, shapely, affine-transformation

I understand that I can use Shapely's `affinity.translate` to translate a geometry like the below:

```
from shapely import affinity
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

poly = Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1)])
poly2 = affinity.translate(poly, xoff=1.0, yoff=0.0)
```

How can I apply this transformation on the bounds of each polygon geometry in a GeoDataFrame and automatically update the position of the geometry as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `apply` function of pandas.

```
from shapely import affinity
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import geopandas

geometries = [Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1)]), Polygon([(10, 10), (11, 10), (11, 11)])]
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'B'], 'geometry': geometries})

#    Name   geometry
# 0  A      POLYGON ((0.00000 0.00000, 1.00000 0.00000, 1....
# 1  B      POLYGON ((10.00000 10.00000, 11.00000 10.00000..

gdf["geometry"] = gdf["geometry"].apply(affinity.translate, xoff=100, yoff=100)

#    Name   geometry
# 0  A      POLYGON ((100.00000 100.00000, 101.00000 100.00000...
# 1  B      POLYGON ((110.00000 110.00000, 111.00000 110.00000...
```

Comment: Thanks, can I apply the same principle to the gdf.bounds? I want to perform the translation on the bounds and update the polygons accordingly...

Comment: I don't think so but I am not sure 100%.